# How to upload a page to web and shows the page when url is given in browser?

Tags: url, html

I have designed a page using photoshop and illustrator for my product.Actually its the first page of our website, construction is not over yet.But I want to upload that one page to web now just for publicity.The thing is that i want to get that page open when the user types url in browser.

So,  What i have to do to upload page to web and shows my page whenever the url is written in browser??Please help...

Comment: Find a hosting service. Follow their instructions.

Comment: You need to get a web host, probably a domain name (although not necessarily a requirement), and then you just need to upload the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Is your page still in an image format or have you converted it to HTML?
If you have converted to HTML, upload it to your server and give the link of the HTML to users to check out the page.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what your problem is but:

- Register a domain with a provider
- Name your html file `index.html` and upload it to the root folder of your web space.